# Is auto as a parameter in a regular function a GCC 4.9 extension?

Tags: c++, gcc, auto, c++14, gcc4.9

gcc 4.9 allows the following code, but gcc 4.8 and clang 3.5.0 reject it.

```
void foo(auto c)
{
    std::cout << c.c_str();
}
```

I get `warning: ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]` in 4.9 but in 4.8 and clang I get `error: parameter declared 'auto'`.

Comment: With gcc 4.9.1, `g++ -std=c++11` gives me "warning: use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration only available with -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y". With `g++ -std=c++14` there's no warning.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Weird, it's definitely not part of C++14 (lambdas, yes, but not other functions).

Comment: @chris: Playing around with gcc 4.9.1, [here's an example](http://codepad.org/mm1jRI4X). The compiler used by codepad.org doesn't handle it, but I get 4 lines of output with the expected size and value on each line. Apparently `foo` acts like a template.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, this is an extension. It's likely to be added to C++17 as part of the 'concepts' proposal, I believe.

Comment: `It's likely to be added to C++17 as part of the 'concepts' proposal, I believe.` Indeed, known as [generic functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4040.pdf) ([dcl.fct]).

Comment: @user657267 The wording used for this in the [Concepts Technical Specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4333.pdf) seems to be "Abbreviated Function Templates".

Comment: @JonathanMee Good to know, I guess "generic function" was too...generic.

Comment: Because it is an extension shouldn't it have been enabled for `gnu++14` dialect and not for  `c++14`?

Comment: @bolov As I understand it, the difference between the 'standard' modes and the 'gnu' modes is that only _non-conforming_ extensions are disabled in the standard modes. Conforming extensions (that is, extensions which modify the behavior of only programs which are ill-formed or have undefined behavior under the C++ spec) are still enabled. `auto` parameters on normal functions is ill-formed under the (current) spec, so this extension is still enabled in the standard mode. To disable all extensions (as much as gcc allows) use `-Werror=pedantic`.

Comment: A year and a half later, concepts won't be in C++17, so generic functions won't be either.

Comment: @Barry "abbreviated function templates"

Comment: `A year and a half later, concepts won't be in C++17, so generic functions won't be either.` a very sad thing indeed.

Comment: `A year and a half later` Concepts will be a thing in C++20.

Answer (score 12):

This is Concepts Lite speak for

```
template<class T>
void foo(T c)
{
    std::cout << c.c_str();
}
```

The `auto` just replaces the more verbose `template<class T>`. Similarly, you can write

```
void foo(Sortable c)
```

as a shorthand for

```
template<class T> 
requires Sortable<T>{}
void foo(T c)
```

Here, `Sortable` is a concept, which is implemented as a conjunction of `constexpr` predicates that formalize the requirements on the template parameter. Checking these requirements is done during name lookup.

In this sense, `auto` is a completely unconstrained template.