# Function returning auto with auto parameter munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

I'm testing out [new feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879705/is-auto-as-a-parameter-in-a-regular-function-a-gcc-4-9-extension) for GCC 4.9 (auto in parameter) and getting some weird bug.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

auto foo(auto v)
{
    for (auto&& i : v)
        std::cout << i;
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
}
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f87f58c6dc0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7e846)[0x7f87f4e4c846]
./a.out[0x400803]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f87f4def76d]
./a.out[0x400881]
```

Also, if I do `return 0` I get:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'auto foo(auto:1) [with auto:1 = std::vector<int>]':
main.cpp:13:34:   required from here
main.cpp:8:12: error: could not convert '0' from 'int' to 'std::vector<int>'
     return 0;
```

Seems strange that both auto are deduced to be the same. What can I do to fix?

---

Note that the following works fine:

```
auto foo(auto v)
{
    return 'a';
}

int main()
{
    char c = foo(42);
}
```

My tests seem to indicate that pointers cause return type and v to be deduced to same. For example `int*` and `make_unique<int>(42)`. However, vector is the one to give error.

Comment: I dont think **parameter** types can be deduced that way

Comment: auto in parameters for non-(generic lambdas) is probably going to be C++17

Answer (score 0):

> I dont think **parameter** types can be deduced that way – sp2danny

I belive that using `auto` like this invokes old `auto` meaning
(AFAIK, in this case `auto`=`int`, and `int` can't be converted to [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)).

---

At the moment it works in lambdas

```
[](const auto& v)->void{for(auto&&i:v) std::cout<<i;}
```

But I think the best solution in this case is to write a template

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T& t){
    for (auto&& i : t)
        std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: he's probably asking for "why does it crash?"

Comment: It's definitely making return type = parameter type. So I don't think it's that.

Comment: @user: Maybe try to modify the function to make it returning `void` instead of `auto`. _I don't have g++ 4.9, so I can't check it out._