# Usage of auto concerning templates and functions

Tags: c++, c++14

Is this the correct C++14 style to pass in a lambda function and return a std::vector that contains n calls to the lambda function?

```
// gen is a lambda function
auto returnN(auto gen, auto n){
    std::vector< decltype(gen()) > vec;
    for(auto i=0; i<n; i++){
       vec.push_back( gen() );
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any templates here. `auto` as a parameter is not C++14.

Comment: @remyabel in gcc 4.9.1 with std=c++14 auto as a parameter actually works

Comment: @bolov It's not C++14, though it is an extension. [Is auto as a parameter in a regular function a GCC 4.9 extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879705/is-auto-as-a-parameter-in-a-regular-function-a-gcc-4-9-extension)

Comment: The use of `auto` as a parameter type is proposed in Concepts Lite, but isn't standard C++ yet.

Comment: You're forcing `i` to be `int`, which might not be large enough. `while (n-- > 0)` might be a better loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

1. You need to explicitly use `template`, unless your compiler allows it as an extension. It might come in C++17.

   [Is auto as a parameter in a regular function a GCC 4.9 extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25879705)
2. You probably want to take the functor/function-pointer by universal reference.
3. You forgot to decay the `vector`'s element-type.
4. Your loop has a loop-variable of type `int`. Whether that is enough...

```
template<class F>
auto returnN(F&& gen, size_t n) {
    std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(gen())>> vec; // Needs to decay
    while(n--)
        vec.push_back(gen());
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: IMHO I don't think there is a need for perfect forwarding of `gen` here. Since you call `gen` multiple times you can't `std::forward` it (except for the very last call... which is not feasible). Since you don't `std::forward` it, then `F const &` is more than enough I think....

Comment: @bolov: Sry about the wrong phrasing. Universal reference does fit much better here. And you really don't want to make it `const`, that might make it unusable. Think about a mutable lambda.

Comment: @bolov `if (n--) { while(n--) vec.push_back(gen()); vec.push_back(std::forward<F>(gen));}` in place of `while`

Comment: @Yakk yes of course, but then on the last call you might get a different type if the `gen` has `operator()` overloaded for `&` and `&&`.

Comment: @Yakk: That's probably over-engineered. Though it's a possiblity.

Comment: I'd probably use `vec.reserve(n);` and replace the explicit loop with `std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), n, std::forward<F>(gen));`, although it's mostly a style difference.

Comment: @Casey: Without `std::forward`, sure. With it, that might be iffy. Not likely, but possible.

Comment: With the -std=c++1y flag it is working on Apples' latest g++ build. I agree with the size_t and n-- advice. Could you explain why the std::decay_t and templating is required?

Comment: @ChadBrewbaker: decaying the template-parameter is neccessary, because we need to get rid of cv-qualifiers and cannot use references. Explicit template is required because C++14 does not support `auto` function-arguments, except for lambdas. C++17 might bring it, or some conforming compiler-extension could support it. Conforming means as long as there's a diagnostic on first encountering that construct, the compiler is free to interpret it as it wants, and hopefully sensibly.

Comment: not familiar with auto, I wonder whether `returnN(f, x)` SFINAE-checks that `f()` is valid before taking that call? Or does it hard-fail later with instantiating the body of `returnN`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: There's no SFINAE at all. Which does not hurt, as it should be a compile-time-error.

Comment: This makes me think that in the general case where it is possible, it may be better to make this a `-> std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(gen())>>` and replace the local variable declaration by `decltype(returnN(std::forward<F>(gen), n)) vec` to make it use SFINAE. So that it is possible to overload `returnN`.