# What's the status of C++17 support in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

Clang has a [nice page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) describing the project status w.r.t. C++1z/C++17 feature support (and C++11 and C++14, it's the same page).

g++ has [a page regarding C++14 features](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html), but I couldn't find anything about C++17/C++1z. Is that being worked on but just not present on the web? For version 5.0?

Comment: C++17 is in early development state and,m as I know,  there's not support for it's features in GCC yet. Even clang has limited and experimental support for it (http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17). On the other hand some progress is being done in GCC too, see: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/370773/ or https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html.

Comment: [libstdc++ 201z](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Updated final nutshell answer:

- GCC 8.x (and later) fully supports all of C++17.
- GCC 7.x supports all of C++17 except for class template argument deduction.
- GCC 6.x (and earlier) has little or no support for C++17 features.

Thanks @JanVanDijk for the [link to the full feature table](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z).

Comment: Support in [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) is still listed as _experimental_.  This is also implied by the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Standards.html#C_002b_002b-Language).  gcc 9 includes [_improved experimental support_](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html#cxx) for c++17

Comment: The manual you linked to says "GCC supports all the changes in the new specification." The word "experimental" is not found on that page.

Comment: that's true, but then the link to follow for further information says that the support is _experimental_.  Also, the first line of the manual only says _GCC supports the original ISO C++ standard published in 1998, and the 2011 and 2014 revisions_

Answer (score 32):

As of today, gcc's C++1z language support is tracked on: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1z.html. For the C++1z status of libstdc++, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z.

Answer (score 7):

There is some support already; The following two summaries are oriented on Clang's list:

Supported (as of July 5th, 2015):

- `auto` for function parameters is supported [since 4.9](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XaghgoilSWqUVzin). This feature is currently considered an extension but is included in the concepts proposal and called "generic functions".
- trigraphs are being ignored by default [since 5.1.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/c0Iu3cyi97CRgY7c)
- `typename` for template template parameters [since 5.1.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/TYoY7uqUiegFmM5P)
- new deduction rules for direct-list-initialization [since 5.1.0](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/06fQUanokhakZPLi)
- `static_assert` without a message [in HEAD](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QXsEiBl24CrNiVwQ)
- `u8` character literals [in HEAD](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qPwxuugN4XKnRvTF)
- Attributes for namespaces or enumerators [in HEAD](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YTXFqBGNEqUHz0pE)

Unsupported (as of July 5th, 2015; with links to a valid example usage):

- [Fold expressions](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YlHnfoTTac6EYyxx)
- [Nested namespace definitions](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jSfvCNdUfnoiqJQr)
- [Constant evaluation for all non-type template arguments](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FjIqvsDxGmGw4BPv)

For the status of implementation of library proposals in libstdc++, [the corresponding manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z) has a list.

Comment: "auto for function parameters" What is this? I cannot find this in the [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) list.

Comment: Trigraphs aren't really a problem. If you want them, you can always define them to be part of the system's source encoding.

Comment: @Suma: "auto for function parameters" is C++14: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14 (while the shown example is probably a gcc extension).

Comment: @Thomas Nope. It's part of a planned feature for C++17; "Generic functions", part of the concepts paper. Generic lambdas are indeed C++14.

Comment: @Columbo: As of 4.9 this must be an extension. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25879737.
You are compiling in C++14 mode, GCC 4.9 doesn't even recognize `-std=c++1z`.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a nice table at cppreference.com that lists supported features for several compilers.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: This actually appears to be more up-to-date and comprehensive than the feature pages maintained by the actual compiler vendors (!!!).

Comment: Actually, the MSVC page is pretty good, it's just hard to find: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance