# How to enable std::experimental::optional on Android

Tags: android, c++, option-type

I'd like to use optionals in my Android app's C++ code, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure the STL to support either std::experimental::optional or std::optional. I get a build failure, "cannot find -lc++experimental," if I just add "-lc++experimental" to the cppFlags. This is what the externalNativeBuild portion of my Gradle file looks like presently.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
        cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-frtti", "-fexceptions"
    }
}
```

How can I enable the use of std::optional or std::experimental::optional?

EDIT: I was able to download boost and use boost::optional instead, which was easy enough since it's a header-only library. Still, it would be nice to know how to to use one of the STLs that ships with the NDK, if that's possible. When I open up $ANDROID_NDK_HOME/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/experimental/optional, I see what looks like an implementation of std::experimental::optional, but it's surrounded by a lot of preprocessor statements that I imagine are disabling it.

Comment: Does your implementation even have that implemented?

Answer (score 0):

`std::optional` is part of the [C++17 STL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). If your compiler supports it add `-std=c++17`otherwise I believe the correct flag is `-std=c++1z`.

[See this discussion for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230201/whats-the-status-of-c1z-c17-support-in-gcc)