# auto parameter type in functions

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, c++17

I would like to know if the standard committee considered expanding the C++14 `auto` keyword to deduce function template parameter type, as it exists today in generic lambdas. ([as can be seen nicely depicted in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233649/893406))

Because it works in lambda functions, it should also work in any function. Of course it would be totally redundant with the classic syntax:

```
template< typename T >
void f(T param);
```

But being able to write this, for the same result:

```
void f(auto param);
```

I think would allow for less clogged code (shorter neater cleaner) and allow a great consistency in this use case:

```
auto v = func1();
f(v);
```

As you can see, we used the auto type deducer to declare `v`, but then we have to use either a hard-typed parameterized function f, or a templated f.
In combination with `auto` we should use `auto`, that would be more consistent.

EDIT: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25879705/893406) indeed asks effectively the same thing, but less directly. And has yet to get the answer that user657267 gives, which I reproduce and extend thereunder.

Comment: This will be in C++17.

Comment: [Is auto as a parameter in a regular function a GCC 4.9 extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25879705/3953764)

Comment: Interesting, who would have thought we could see something like that in C++ :)

Comment: now the remaining "question in the question" would be to have a hint about the level of likeliness that this will actually end up in C++17. Unfortunately it seems it got dragged along a big new feature: concepts. I didn't even know concepts were being considered at all. It makes me feel that including concepts now would be a big change, and poses a risk to this generic function feature of being dropped along if concepts are dropped. I feel it would have a nicer place alone it its own right... :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to Piotr pointing this other question asking about the same thing, I found the information in a comment that will resolve this, here it is:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4040.pdf

page 16, chapter 5.1.1 named `generic functions`

> A generic function is a function template whose
>   template-parameter-list has a parameterdeclaration whose
>   type-specifier is either auto or a constrained-type-name.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> auto f(auto x); // Ok
> void sort(C& c); // Ok (assuming C names a concept)
> ```
>
> — end example ]

This seems rather positive :)

followed by the excpected obvious wording, that matches generic lambda:

> The declaration of a generic function has a template-parameter-list
>   that consists of one invented type template-parameter for each
>   occurrence of auto.
>
> [ Example: The following generic function declarations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> template<typenaem T>  
> conxtexpr bool C() { ... }  
> auto f(auto x, const C& y);  
> template<typename T1, C T2> 
> auto f(T1 x, const T2& y);
> ```
>
> The type of y is a type parameter constrained by C. — end example ]

Comment: also described at cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: C++20 now allows [`auto` as a function parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355539/975097).