# Are there negative ramifications of using auto as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, auto

In the spirit of generic programming, I've created the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Functor
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "Functor operator called." << std::endl;
    }
};

void Function()
{
    std::cout << "Function called." << std::endl;
}

void Call( auto & fp )
{
    static int i;
    std::cout << "Unified calling..." << &i << std::endl;
    fp();
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    Functor functor;
    std::function< void() > function = Function;

    std::cout << "Begin testing..." << std::endl;
    Call( functor );
    Call( function );
    std::cout << "End testing." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Compiled with: g++ main.cpp -std=c++14
output:
Begin testing...
Unified calling...0x100402080
Functor operator called.
Unified calling...0x100402090
Function called.
End testing.
```

From what I can tell by the address of static, this produces two different functions, so it seems to me like a template shorthand, of a sort. My instinct is that one function to maintain is better than multiple ones, however, besides being mindful of the non-shared static variables, am I missing something that might make this a poor choice, instead of multiple function definitions?

Comment: You can only use `auto` in generic lambdas... For functions, use templates

Comment: It is a non-standard extension, a shorthand for templates, apparently [likely to be added to the C++17 standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879705/is-auto-as-a-parameter-in-a-regular-function-a-gcc-4-9-extension).  Not a part of c++14.

Comment: @HostileFork Not going to be in C++17.

Comment: @Barry Probably for the best... but perhaps you can tell the author of the answer there to update from "likely" to "not happening" w/appropriate reference.

Comment: @HostileFork Threw a comment on that answer as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are. They are forbidden by current C++ standard.

```
void Call( auto & fp )
```

is a compilation error on standard-conforming compiler.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible, is the main flaw.

`auto` just means type deduction at the point of initialisation. It is not an "any" type. So, using `auto` in this way would mean your function would have to be a template. In C++17, this will be possible and indeed an `auto` parameter will automatically make the function a template (personally I find this extremely confusing, but oh well). But for now, no.

Comment: It is exactly *any* type for generic lambdas.

Comment: @SergeyA Which would be relevant if `Call` were a generic lambda?

Comment: @SergeyA: It's not - it gets replaced by whatever type has been deduced. The point I'm trying to make (admittedly quite badly) is that `auto` is not a type in itself like some newbies think. An object can't "be" `auto`. And I strongly suspect that misconception is at the heart of this question.

Comment: Possibly. I see what you mean better now, like auto is not `boost::any`. But still, it is not deduction at the point of initializion with generic lambdas, so the statement does not cover all the cases. I think, the answer would be better if reworded with more clarity.

Comment: @SergeyA: The only thing that really matters is that the OP's code is ill-formed.