# auto type deduction for argument with default value

Tags: c++, c++14, default-value, auto

I apologize for not having time enough to make a deep investigation and relying on your help instead.

Consider the simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class PrintColour
{
    COLOUR_1        =   0,
    COLOUR_2        =   1,
};
 
void colour( auto c = PrintColour::COLOUR_1 )
{
    switch ( c )
    {
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_1:
            std::cout << "Colour 1" << std::endl;
            break;
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_2:
            std::cout << "Colour 2" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main( )
{
//  colour( ); couldn't deduce template parameter ‘auto:1’
    colour( PrintColour::COLOUR_1 );    // Fine!
}
```

This code exactly as it is compiles and runs without a problem. If I uncomment the `colour( );`, though, g++ fires the error:

```
auto_param.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
auto_param.cpp:27:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘colour()’
  colour( );
          ^
auto_param.cpp:13:6: note: candidate: template<class auto:1> void colour(auto:1)
 void colour( auto c = PrintColour::COLOUR_1 )
      ^~~~~~
auto_param.cpp:13:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
auto_param.cpp:27:10: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘auto:1’
  colour( );
          ^
```

It is possible that I am just missing a silly point, or it is possible that I am really stupid and misunderstood the whole thing.

Should I be able to declare a function parameter as `auto` while still being able to give it a default value in C++11 or C++14?

I thought the given default value would be enough to let compiler deduce the parameter type...

---

**EDIT 1:**

It think I need to make my question clearer so it won't be mistaken by [Is there a way to pass auto as an argument in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944985/)

The point here is not passing `auto` to a function, but having `auto` in conjunction with a *default value* for the argument, something not considered in the aforementioned question.

**EDIT 2:**

As clarified in comments here, C++11 does not have such a feature of passing `auto` as parameter, but C++14 and on (g++ 6.3.1 defaults to "gnu++14") seem to. My original question is not related to C++11, though, and my question is not whether C++11 supports `auto` parameters. I was relying on `auto` as parameter, but forgot to double check the minimum standard version for it. My apologies and I fixed that now.

```
g++ -std=c++11 auto_param.cpp -o auto_param
auto_param.cpp:13:14: error: use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
```

I hope it to be clear the difference between my question and [Is auto as a parameter in a regular function a GCC 4.9 extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879705/). Please tell me if not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pass auto as an argument in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944985/is-there-a-way-to-pass-auto-as-an-argument-in-c)

Comment: *Assuming* `auto` here is just a syntactic sugar for template parameter, you cannot call this function w/o arguments, because it's parameter type cannot be deduced in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is auto as a parameter in a regular function a GCC 4.9 extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879705/is-auto-as-a-parameter-in-a-regular-function-a-gcc-4-9-extension)

Answer (score 4):

No, [it is a non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

> **Non-deduced contexts**.
>
> In the following cases, the types, templates, and
>   non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in
>   template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments
>   that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a
>   template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not
>   explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> <...>
>
> 4) A
>   template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter
>   that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which
>   argument deduction is being done

Comment: You are talking about template argument deduction. The OP is asking about deduction for `auto`.

Comment: @R Sahu how does the type deduction for "auto" parameter (defined in mini-concepts TS) differ from the one for template parameters?

Comment: `auto` types for function parameters are not supported in C++11. It is only supported for lambda functions in C++14. There is a proposal to support it in C++17. I haven't seen that proposal. I can't tell how similar it is for template argument deduction. it's not something we can even discuss meaningfully when dealing with C++11 or C++14.

Comment: I really can't tell if a `template` argument is different from `auto`. @R Sahu, could you please point me any directions?

Comment: @fljx, I have not been able to track down the C++17 proposal yet.

Comment: as far as I know, `void foo(auto a)` is intended to be the same as `template <class T> void foo(T a)`.

Comment: I tried to find out from C++14 draft (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) whether `auto` is really just syntactic sugar for `template` but it is not clear to me. The best I could find is "auto: placeholder for a type to be deduced" (7.1.6.2 and 7.1.6.4). Could anybody help, please?

Comment: @fljx it is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4641.pdf) See 7.1.6.4: "Similarly, if a placeholder appears in a parameter type of a function declaration, the function declaration declares an abbreviated function template"

Answer (score 3):

> Should I be able to declare a function parameter as auto while still being able to give it a default value in C++11 or C++14?

I don't know if C++17 support it but, as far I know, C++11 and C++14 don't support an `auto` parameter for a function (C++14 support it only for lambda functions)

> I thought the given default value would be enough to let compiler deduce the parameter type...

If instead of `auto` you accept to use a template type, you have to add the default template type also.

Something as follows

```
template <typename T = decltype(PrintColour::COLOUR_1)>
void colour( T c = PrintColour::COLOUR_1 )
{
    switch ( c )
    {
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_1:
            std::cout << "Colour 1" << std::endl;
            break;
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_2:
            std::cout << "Colour 2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I know: is redundant.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP says

> I was just wondering if I couldn't make my code more readable by not repeating

More readable probably not but... if you want it not repeating... I know that macros are distilled evil but... if you **really** want avoid repeating...

```
#define noRepeat(r, n, a, b) \
r n (decltype(b) a = b)

noRepeat(void, colour, c, PrintColour::COLOUR_1)
{
    switch ( c )
    {
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_1:
            std::cout << "Colour 1" << std::endl;
            break;
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_2:
            std::cout << "Colour 2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

or also (if you want make the trick on parameter basis)

```
#define parDef(a, b)  decltype(b) a = b

void colour ( parDef(c, PrintColour::COLOUR_1), parDef(d, 5) )
{
    switch ( c )
    {
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_1:
            std::cout << "Colour 1" << std::endl;
            break;
        case PrintColour::COLOUR_2:
            std::cout << "Colour 2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @max66. I was just wondering if I couldn't make my code more readable by not repeating `( PrintColour c = PrintColour::COLOUR_1 )`. I know it didn't work, but I still want to learn why (and possibly learn another way to tidy my code as well). As from @Igor R. comment, I was considering `auto` to be "syntactic sugar".

Comment: @fljx - I see... well... if you want avoid repeating... answer improved.

Comment: Your edit is tempting... I am considering something like `#define def_deduce( p, def_value ) decltype( def_value ) p = def_value` and later `void colour( def_deduce( c, PrintColour::COLOUR_1 ) )` but, as you stated. macros are ignominious. Last note, according to g++, it seems that C++14 supports `auto` as parameter.

Comment: @fljx - g++ accept `auto` if you forget `-pedantic`; with `-pedantic` you get an error; C++14 accept `auto` for lambda functions only (as far I know) but if you try something like `auto colour = [](auto c = PrintColour::COLOUR_1) { };`, works when you call `colour( PrintColour::COLOUR_1 );` but when you call `colour();` you get an error similar to `colour( ); couldn't deduce template parameter ‘auto:1’` (both clang++ and g++).