# Use of auto as return and parameters type in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14

In the 4th edition of Bjarne Stroustrup book (The C++ programing language) we read that:

> Using auto , we avoid redundancy and writing long type names. This is especially important in generic programming where the exact type of an object can be hard for the programmer to know and the type names can be quite long (§4.5.1).

So, to understand the importance of this type. I made this small test program:

```
#include <iostream>

/*-----------------------------*/
auto multiplication(auto a, auto b)
{
    return a * b;
}


int main()
{
  auto c = multiplication(5,.134);
  auto d = 5 * .134;
  std::cout<<c<<"\n"<<d<<"\n";

}
```

The stdout of this program (compiled with -std=C++14):

```
0
0.67
```

I am wondering why I got different results (types) with c and d variables even if the return type of multiplication function is auto.

**EDIT:**
My GCC version: `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: It's best to use `auto` when the result should be obvious to the compiler. In this case it's possible that using `auto` as an argument type leaves it ambiguous and subject to interpretation. The result of `int` * `float` is a `float`, but if the arguments are guessed incorrectly it could interpret as `int` * `int` inside that method.

Comment: This is a non-standard extension. `C++14` does not allow `auto` parameters for functions.

Comment: For what it's worth, this code generates errors like "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'multiplication' with no type" or "warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 0.134 to 0 [-Wliteral-conversion]" depending on the compiler used. The `clang` LLVM-based compiler gives some really good explanations as to what's going wrong, so it's worth checking as a reference in cases like this.

Comment: @tadman did you compile with `-std=c++14`? "declaration with no type" sounds like a C++03 interpretation of the declaration.

Comment: If you change the code to be actually legal C++14, you'll get the expected result. https://wandbox.org/permlink/eTZilBZhK19NOkDw

Comment: @Quentin Ah, that does resolve the issue on one side, but was just doing a quick check with [Codepad](http://codepad.org) where it [errored out](http://codepad.org/3yhmMc9C). On the `clang` side you get "error: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype".

Comment: I can't repeat this with `GCC v7.1.0` it looks like a bug

Comment: I recommend compiling with flag `-pedantic-errors` to enforce standards compliance.

Comment: My GCC version: `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609`

Comment: @Galik When I use --pedantic-errors I got an error: error: ISO C++ forbids use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration [-Wpedantic]

Comment: This gives the strange result with gcc-5, but the expected one with gcc-6 and later, so bug and already fixed.

Comment: This is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64969

Comment: @MohamedAmjadLASRI Yes because using `auto` in parameters is non-standard. It won't work on other compilers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To start with, your code makes use of [gcc extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879705/is-auto-as-a-parameter-in-a-regular-function-a-gcc-4-9-extension), namely *auto function parameters*.

I guess your *gcc* version does not work with the extension properly and provides an incorrect result (with *gcc 7.1* I have `0.67 0.67` even using auto parameters).

The normal way to rewrite your function in a standard *C++* is to apply templates:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto multiplication(T a, U b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

and let the compiler to deduce return type.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the right explanation. Using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ` the output is `auto multiplicatio(auto:1, auto:2) [with auto:1 = int; auto:2 = double]`. `T` cannot be deduced `int` and `double` at the same time.

Comment: @DavideSpataro What version of `GCC` did you use?

Comment: Not the newest one but should be new enough: `g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)`

Comment: @DavideSpataro I tried *gcc 5.3* and *gcc 5.4* on wandbox and both gave the same result: `0 0.67`. On the other hand, *gcc 7.1* gives `0.67 0.67`. That is why I have supposed that the extension didn't work correctly and generated a template similar to the mentioned in the answer with some type of arguments cast.

Comment: I also think that the extension does not work properly in oder version. Infact, using a lambda instead of a normal function it work just fine. `auto multiplication = [](auto a, auto b) {return a * b;};` outputs `0.67 0.67`

Comment: @DavideSpataro Yeah, but lambdas are the standard way to do the things and auto parameters are not :) So the extension seems not to work properly on the older gcc versions.

Comment: The two parameters are deduced separately, not together - `auto mult(auto a, auto b) { return a*b; }` is equivalent to `template <class T, class U> auto mult(T a, U b) { return a*b; }`

Answer (score 7):

To start with Bjarne Stroustrup in his 4th edition of his seminal book ["The C++ Programming Language"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840) doesn't refer to the use of `auto` as rendered in your code example. But rather to the standard use of the [`auto` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) as:

- Specifier for variables where their type is going to be deduced by its initializer (e.g., `auto i = 0;`).
- Specifier for function's return type where it's going to be deduced by its trailing return type or from its return statement.

  `auto foo(int a, int b) {return a + b; }`

In your example you're referring to the use of `auto` as a placeholder as suggested by [C++ extensions for Concepts (N4674)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4674.pdf) proposal. Unfortunately, this is not standard C++ yet. It was to be accepted in C++17 but it didn't make it. Hopes now rise for C++20. However, use of `auto` like that is provided by GCC as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Concepts.html#C_002b_002b-Concepts). Work on C++ concepts for GCC started very early, it even predates the advent of C++11. At some point work on concepts was abandoned and then restarted under another name namely Concepts Lite. Support back then was pretty unstable (e.g., GCC version 5.4). Thus, what you're experiencing is a GCC bug. In more recent versions of GCC this bug has been corrected.