# Parameter packs and function declaration

Tags: c++

I have three files - `lib.h` with function declarations, `lib.cpp` with implementation and `main.cpp` entry point. Their contents is just as simple as:

```
//lib.h
#pragma once

void func1();
void func2();
void funcN();

//lib.cpp
#include "lib.h"

void func1(){}
void func2(){}
void funcN(){}

//main.cpp
#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it like so:

```
$ g++ main.cpp lib.cpp
```

So far, so good. But now I want to use parameter pack in one of my functions. Like so:

```
//change in lib.cpp

void funcN(int i, auto... j) {

}
```

I change lib.h and main.cpp respectively:

```
//change in lib.h
void funcN(int, auto...);

//change in main.cpp

int main() {
    funcN(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

But now, when I compile it with

```
$ g++ main.cpp lib.cpp
```

I get this error message:

> main.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `void funcN(int, int, ...)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I know that this error is because of `auto...` and I know that I can probably solve it, if I put implementation inside `lib.h`, but this looks nasty  - to have some implementations in one file and other implementations in another. I would like to know, how they do it in real world practice.

Comment: You may want to add a `-pedantic` flag. [It's not standard C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d55fca982f36d9ae). It seem like an extension that transforms that function into a template. And well, [a template better be defined in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `auto` as a function parameter is **not** Standard C++. Your code is currently not valid C++. See [Is auto as a parameter in a regular function a GCC 4.9 extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879705/is-auto-as-a-parameter-in-a-regular-function-a-gcc-4-9-extension) for more information. Note that `auto` as a function parameter (along with shorthand concept syntax) was not added to C++20's working draft yet.

Regardless, using `auto` in that manner is just shorthand for function template definition - this means that your need to **define** your function in the header.

Here's a solution that's valid C++:

```
// lib.h
template <typename... Js>
void funcN(int i, Js... js) {

}
```

More information: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score -1):

In this case `auto...` does not declare parameter pack with auto type. It declares an unnamed parameter followed by regular ellipsis because compiler allows to omit comma before elipses. Declare it without `auto` if you want to get a regular variadic function

```
void funcN(int i, ...)
```

Or as a proper template in header file if you want to get real parameter pack

```
template<typename... TArgs> void
function(int i, TArgs... args) {}
```

Comment: In standard C++ `auto` is not allowed in a parameter declaration at all, so it doesn't really define anything (and the ellipsis in `auto ... j` cannot be a regular C style ellipsis however you spin it).  It's a gcc extension, and it does mean "parameter pack with auto type".